# Is there a way to combine multiple pnp provisioning xml into one?

Tags: xml, sharepoint, provisioning

I have multiple Provisining XML that i want to combine into one file. This is to make an better structure.
For example i have one xml that creates a sharepoint lists.

File Name.xml

```
    <pnp:Lists>
        <pnp:ListInstance Title="Important Document Library"
                Description="A list of Important Document"
                OnQuickLaunch="true"
                TemplateType="101"
                Url="Lists/ImportantDocumentLibrary"
                EnableVersioning="false">
            <pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
                <pnp:ContentTypeBinding ContentTypeID="0x01010060E8334F51D149B2A2E584AD87182B06" Default="true"/>
            </pnp:ContentTypeBindings>
        </pnp:ListInstance>
    </pnp:Lists>
```

How do i put this file into another xml. I tried to do the following but dosent work.

Main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:Provisioning
    xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema">
    <pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-TEMPLATE">
        <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="TEMPLATE" Version="1">
            <xi:include
                xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" href="Name.xml" />
            </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
        </pnp:Templates>
    </pnp:Provisioning>
```

Answer (score 2):

Late answer, but maybe helps others.
Try replacing the first line in File Name.xml with:

```
<pnp:Lists xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema">
```

Note: "2016/05" should be the same throughout your xml files. If you use another version of the PnP schema, make sure to update this value as well.

Comment: yea i solved it the same way as you Doug, needed to add xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2016/05/ProvisioningSchema" to the first element in the xml im including. just havent answered my own question yet :)